# .htaccess multiple public folders

Tags: php, .htaccess

My application is quite large and it is split into areas and I would like to have a seperate public folder in each of these areas for images and scripts that are only needed within that specific area.

I am currently directing all traffic to my public folder with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ public/     [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

And in the public folder I have the following .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Is it possible to allow requests to:

```
http://example.com/area/public/scripts/myscript.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your root .htaccess to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ public/     [L]
RewriteRule ^((?!area/public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. It could be an issue with how I am routing though.

Comment: What happens when you enter `http://example.com/area/public/scripts/myscript.js` in your browser? Is there any .htaccess in `/area/` or `/area/public/` etc folders?

Comment: I am getting my error page saying page not found. There are no other .htaccess file on the site other than the root and the main public folder as mentioned above.

Comment: And there is no 404 for `http://example.com/area/public/scripts/myscript.js` if you keep your rules as shown in question?

Comment: No I am getting my own error page again. For some reason the file is being treated like a view rather than a file.

Comment: To test whether my rule works or not add `R` flag in the rule like: `RewriteRule ^((?!area/public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC,R]` and see what URL you get in browser for `http://example.com/area/public/scripts/myscript.js`

Comment: Earlier you wrote `/area/` but your latest comment shows `/areas/` which one is correct?

Comment: If it is `areas` then rule will be: `RewriteRule ^((?!areas/public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]`

Comment: I have a folder called areas and then within that I have my area folders e.g. user, admin, etc. So to access the public folder in the User area it would be areas/user/public. I have tried !areas/user/public/ and !user/public/ Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: ok just try: `RewriteRule ^((?!areas/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]` first and see how it behaves.